# Lag and Lead to next month

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

```
TABLE: HIST
CUSTOMER   MONTH   PLAN
1          1       A
1          2       B
1          2       C
1          3       D
```

If I query:

```
select h.*, lead(plan) over (partition by customer order by month) np from HIST h
```

I get:

```
CUSTOMER   MONTH   PLAN   np
1          1       A      B
1          2       B      C
1          2       C      D
1          3       D      (null)
```

But I wanted

```
CUSTOMER   MONTH   PLAN   np
1          1       A      B
1          2       B      D
1          2       C      D
1          3       D      (null)
```

Reason being, next month to `2` is `3`, with `D`. I'm guessing `partition by customer order by month` doesn't work the way I thought.

Is there a way to achieve this in Oracle 12c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `RANGE` partitioning with the `MIN` analytic function.  Like this:

```
select h.*, 
       min(plan) over 
           (partition by customer 
            order by month 
            range between 1 following and 1 following) np 
from HIST h;
```

> ```
> +----------+-------+------+----+
> | CUSTOMER | MONTH | PLAN | NP |
> +----------+-------+------+----+
> |        1 |     1 | A    | B  |
> |        1 |     2 | B    | D  |
> |        1 |     2 | C    | D  |
> |        1 |     3 | D    |    |
> +----------+-------+------+----+
> ```

When you use `RANGE` partitioning, you are telling Oracle to make the windows based on the *values* of the column you are ordering by rather than making the windows based on the rows.

So, e.g.,

```
ROWS BETWEEN 1 following and 1 following
```

... will make a window containing the next row.

```
RANGE BETWEEN 1 following and 1 following
```

... will make a window containing all the rows having the next value for `month`.

#### UPDATE

If it is possible that some values for `MONTH` might be skipped for a given customer, you can use this variant:

```
select h.*, 
       first_value(plan) over 
          (partition by customer 
           order by month 
           range between 1 following and unbounded following) np 
from h
```

> ```
> +----------+-------+------+----+
> | CUSTOMER | MONTH | PLAN | NP |
> +----------+-------+------+----+
> |        1 |     1 | A    | B  |
> |        1 |     3 | B    | D  |
> |        1 |     3 | C    | D  |
> |        1 |     4 | D    |    |
> +----------+-------+------+----+
> ```

Comment: Comment on my own answer.  `FIRST_VALUE` is not supposed to be deterministic.  I thought I would have to pre-sort the rows to guarantee getting `B` in the first row instead of `C`.  But I cannot get it to every return `C` in the first row, even if I pre-sort the rows so that `C` would come first.  Any comments?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LAG`/`LEAD` twice. The first time to check for duplicate months and to set the value to `NULL` in those months and the second time use `IGNORE NULLS` to get the next monthly value.

It has the additional benefit that if months are skipped then it will still find the next value.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bde7e/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE HIST ( CUSTOMER, MONTH, PLAN ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 'G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 5, 'H' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER,
       MONTH,
       PLAN,
       LEAD( np ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY MONTH, PLAN, ROWNUM ) AS np
FROM   (
  SELECT h.*,
         CASE MONTH
         WHEN LAG( MONTH ) OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY MONTH, PLAN, ROWNUM )
         THEN NULL
         ELSE PLAN
         END AS np
  FROM   hist h
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bde7e/1/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMER | MONTH | PLAN |     NP |
|----------|-------|------|--------|
|        1 |     1 |    A |      B |
|        1 |     2 |    B |      D |
|        1 |     2 |    C |      D |
|        1 |     3 |    D | (null) |
|        2 |     1 |    E |      G |
|        2 |     1 |    F |      G |
|        2 |     3 |    G |      H |
|        2 |     5 |    H | (null) |
```

Answer (score 2):

Just so that it is listed here as an option for Oracle 12c (onward), you can use an apply operator for this style of problem

```
select
     h.customer, h.month, h.plan, oa.np
from hist h
outer apply (
  select
       h2.plan as np
  from hist h2
  where h.customer = h.customer
  and h2.month > h.month
  order by month
  fetch first 1 rows only
  ) oa
order by
     h.customer, h.month, h.plan
```

I don't know of any Oracle 12c public fiddles so, an example in SQL Server can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cd95e/1

```
| customer | month | plan |     np |
|----------|-------|------|--------|
|        1 |     1 |    A |      C |
|        1 |     2 |    B |      D |
|        1 |     2 |    C |      D |
|        1 |     3 |    D | (null) |
```

Comment: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) is for Oracle - you can also change the database using the drop-down in the top left of the page.

Comment: @MTO thanks, but it isn't Oracle 12c (nor is rextester or dbfiddle), the apply operator is not available in 11g

Comment: [https://livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com) is Oracle's own service and is running Oracle 18c. (But you do need to sign up for an account)

Comment: @MTO thanks again. Yes I'm aware of the service, but was trying to supply a fiddle address not behind any login. As yet I'm not aware of any, I'm sure it will happen one day, but sadly not yet.